# switching between data tables, and saving charts i made

Tags: datatable, bar-chart, spotfire, tibco

I imported two data tables, say, "Baseball player data" and "Baseball team data." And I created one bar chart, manipulated the horizontal categories and vertical values...colors...titles...etc. for "Baseball player data."

[image: Player data]

And then I decide to work on "Baseball team data," and after playing around with it, I come back to "Baseball player data" data table. When I come back, all the work I did on it were all deleted, and refreshed to its default setting.

Is there any way that I can retain what I've been doing on the first data table, after I changed to the other data table, other than creating two separate bar charts? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best practice *not* create your analytic in this manner, but if you insist the best way to *save* your work would be to **bookmark** it which can be done with this icon: [image]

Be sure to read up on the [abilities and limitations](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.3/doc/html/bm/bm_what_are_bookmarks.htm) of bookmarks.

Comment: can you explain why it's not the best practice to do this way?

Comment: Well, so much is reliant on the underlying data. Custom expressions, filter schemes, property controls, etc. it's like building a house and then swapping the foundation out. Just because it's possible doesn't mean it is practical or works out nicely. You have a good chance of running into problems later and making your analytic static versus dynamic @EricKim